# Creating a file, read it and discard

Tags: java

I'm getting a file from a HTTP request and I need to read and search for a string.
My problem is that the file is not on the system so I need to `transferTo` a created file.

My question is: where do usually hosts create this temporary files? I want to read the file, search for how many times a string appears and delete the file? Is this the way things are done?

```
  public static int readTestCaseCode(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    File file = new File(//Do I need to specify a location?)
    multipartFile.transferTo();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to store it as a file? You can search for the string on the fly as the bytes arrive from the server.

Comment: How large is the file? Can't you just keep it in memory rather than storing it as a file?

Comment: @Henry same microsecond :)

Comment: Usually temp files are placed at directory specified in the property `java.io.tmpdir`

Comment: It's just plain text. Can thousands of lines but nothing more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the static factory method `File#createTempFile(String, String)` which exactly creates what the name says.

```
File file = File.createTempFile("myFile", ".exe");
```

You can also omit the ending and just pass `null`, which then will be filled with `".tmp"`, e.g.

```
File file = File.createTempFile("myFile", null);
```

The file can then afterwards be deleted by invoking the `File#delete()` method:

```
file.delete();
```

Comment: @user9176898 glad i could help. Although i need to mention that this only creates an empty file, you still have to add content to it

Comment: I think `multipartFile.transferTo(file);` does that.